# Using group_by and acf (autocorrelation function) with long form data

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Good evening,

My question is similar to a question asked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSqBd.png), but my data are in long form and I have multiple grouping variables. I did try to flatten my data and follow the pipeline in the linked post, but was unable to reach a correct end point.

Consider the data frame (df) below that contains time series data, across two trials, two nodes, and two people.

```
df = data.frame(
  trial = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  time = c(180,180,190,190,200, 200),
  node = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
  person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  estimate = seq(1:12))
```

Should an individual simply want to estimate autocorrelation on the first 12 estimates the following code would work just fine and generates the 11 AC estimates for the 12 observations

```
df %>% 
  do(ac = acf(df$estimate, lag.max = 10)) %>%
  pluck("ac", 1)
```

**output**

```
[1,]  1.00000000
 [2,]  0.75000000
 [3,]  0.50699301
 [4,]  0.27797203
 [5,]  0.06993007
 [6,] -0.11013986
 [7,] -0.25524476
 [8,] -0.35839161
 [9,] -0.41258741
[10,] -0.41083916
[11,] -0.34615385
```

However, in the provided data there are additional grouping factors such that for each participant there should be 2 autocorrelation estimates for each time point for each trial from each person.

The way I would tackle this problem through past experience is to use `group_by` such as the provided code below:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(node, trial, person) %>%
  do(ac = acf(df$estimate, lag.max = 10)) %>%
  pluck("ac", 1)
```

However the outcome of this series of dplyr, purrr, and acf commands outputs the the identical output as the code I presented above if I were to estimate autocorrelation for a single participant across a single node,trial.

**Question: How do I (we) modifiy the code to output a new variable in the current dataframe that is equal to the autocorrelation estimate for the unique time x trial x node x person**

Where the intended variable within df would look as follows.

Note, t = time, p = person, tr = trial,N = node, AC = auto correlation where
ACT1P1Tr1N1 is equal to the auto correlation estimate for time point one, person 1, trial 1, and node 1 estimated from the `estimate` variable. `ac` is the intended variable to be added to the existing data frame `df`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your desired outcome looks like. However, your code is not working as expected, because you use `df$estimate` which is the ungrouped `estimate`.

Further, `dplyr::do` is superseeded. We can use `dplyr::summarise` (if needed in combination with `across()` to replace the dot `.`) instead. However, in your example the grouping leaves two observations per group:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(node, trial, person) %>%
  summarise(ac = list(acf(estimate, lag.max = 10))) 

#> A tibble: 12 x 4
#> Groups:   node, trial [6]
#>   node trial person ac    
#>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <list>
#>     1     1      1 <acf> 
#>     1     1      2 <acf> 
#>     1     2      1 <acf> 
#>     1     2      2 <acf> 
#>     1     3      1 <acf> 
#>     1     3      2 <acf> 
#>     2     1      1 <acf> 
#>     2     1      2 <acf> 
#>     2     2      1 <acf> 
#>     2     2      2 <acf> 
#>     2     3      1 <acf> 
#>     2     3      2 <acf>
```

Comment: Right okay, this is close. Sorry I wasn't as clear as I could be. The intended result would include a new vector, as you created that would show the auto correlation estimate for each node/trial/person pair.  I will add in a table to the original post to show what the intended output vector would look like.

Comment: sorry another thing, it looks like the suggested code is outputting 1 for each act estimate and only using an n of 1 where the n should be equal to the number of time points (3)